# numba @vectorize target='parallel' TypeError

Tags: python, numba

If I define

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.vectorize
def nb_vec(x):
    if x>0:
        x=x+100
    return x
```

then

```
x=np.random.random(1000000)
nb_vec(x)
```

run without problem

But If I add target option like

```
@nb.vectorize(target='parallel')
def nb_vec(x):
    if x>0:
        x=x+100
    return x
```

then

```
x=np.random.random(1000000)
nb_vec(x)
```

outputs error message

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 x=np.random.random(1000000)
>   ----> 2 nb_vec(x)
>
> TypeError: ufunc 'nb_vec' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numba 0.46 the `numba.vectorize` decorator without signature will create a *dynamic universal function*, that means it compiles the code based on the types when called. So you don't need to supply a signature.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize()
def nb_vec(x):
    if x > 0:
        x = x + 100
    return x

>>> nb_vec
<numba._DUFunc 'nb_vec'>
>>> nb_vec.types
[]
>>> nb_vec(np.ones(5))
array([101., 101., 101., 101., 101.])
>>> nb_vec.types
['d->d']
```

However if you specify `target='parallel'` then it will create a normal universal function. So it only supports the *provided* signatures. In your case you omitted the signatures so it actually doesn't support any inputs.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize(target='parallel')
def nb_vec(x):
    if x > 0:
        x = x + 100
    return x

>>> nb_vec
<ufunc 'nb_vec'>
>>> nb_vec.types
[]
```

The solution here is to specify a signature with the appropriate types when you use parallel vectorize:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize(
    [nb.int32(nb.int32), 
     nb.int64(nb.int64), 
     nb.float32(nb.float32), 
     nb.float64(nb.float64)], 
    target='parallel')
def nb_vec(x):
    if x > 0:
        x = x + 100
    return x
```